# Cannot filter rows in the SSRS Report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have one SSRS Reports that contains Year Filters (Start Year and End Year). If user inputs Start Year as 2012 and End Year as 2013, then the months and Quarterly figures are listed as

Jan-x   Feb-x  ...... Dec -x   Q1-X  Q2- X  Q3-X  Budget Forecast- X   Budget Actual - X    (Where X= Start Year & End Year)

Hence counting both the years there are 34 (17 *2) columns.

To lay down the data into these years, the report is actually a matrix /pivot because the SQL Query has rows that contain data which are summed and converted into columns into the report.

Now if the data in ALL those 34 columns is 0 or NULL,then those rows should be eliminate. If any of columns contains even a single value, even a $1, then those rows should be VISIBLE.

To easy to say, If the summation of 34 columns is 0/NULL, then those rows should not be visible else it should be visible.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the query you are using to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest amending the report's query to exclude returning rows where the value is 0 or NULL.